# React - Button to open a Modal of Images

Tags: reactjs

Right now I have a App set up to take in Hotels and Images, then a Component to display the Rooms, however some of the Hotels have more than one image so I want to display them in a Modal that pops up, however I'm not sure how to do this or even get the Modal component to display

I've included the code in question below and I have made a seperate Modal Component, this is all linked at the following codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-rumple-8z0tho?file=/src/Components/Hotel.js

Comment: Looks like you made some empty placeholders for the modal component and its styles. What exactly is your challenge? The styling part? Making the modal reusable and injecting data into it and/or returning data to the component which called it? In current form your question is too general and could roughly be described as a request for code, which, for obvious reasons, is *off-topic* on [SO]. Before you should ask for help regarding any particular task you should have an attempt to it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Since I noticed you used `data-bs-target="#exampleModal"`, I figured you are using Bootstrap 5.

Here's a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-moon-mhfpzq?file=/src/Components/Hotel.js).

Changes overview:

- added [bootstrap 5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap),
- added [jotai](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jotai), to manage shared state between `<Hotel />` and `<ModalHotel />`. Note: you don't have to use `jotai`, you can use any other state management plugin of your choice, or `React.useContext`
- on button click I pass current hotel's array of images to images atom, which is looped inside the modal
- fixed filtering
- renamed `[hotel, setHotel]` to `[hotels, setHotels]` and `hotels` to `getHotels`.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not actually using Bootstrap, but this gives me a good start! (and maybe I should look at BS5 for some styling options)

Comment: @SCOCB, in that case you'd have to code your own modal. It might look like a small task but it's not, if you consider all devices, eventual scrolling of modal content, eventual opening/closing animations, etc...